# Using Resque-Scheduler with Docker-Compose - Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, redis, docker-compose, resque-scheduler

I'm trying to run my rails app, resque and redis. Using foreman etc my setup works fine but when I try to run it in Docker using docker-compose I get:

```
app_1       | 21:03:13 resque.1 | Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on redis://redis:6379 (SocketError)
app_1       | 21:03:13 resque.1 | Original Exception (Redis::CannotConnectError): Error connecting to Redis on redis://redis:6379 (SocketError)
```

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add bash build-base libxml2-dev libxslt-dev postgresql postgresql-dev

VOLUME ["/code"]
WORKDIR /code
```

My Docker Compose YML looks like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        bundle check || bundle install
        bundle exec rake db:migrate; rake db:seed
        bundle exec foreman start
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis/5
  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.5-alpine
```

My procfile:

```
web:       bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
resque:    bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=*
scheduler: bundle exec rake resque:scheduler
```

my config/initializers/resque.rb

```
redis_url = ENV["REDIS_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379"

Redis.current = Redis.new(url: redis_url)
Resque.redis = Redis.current
```

and my lib/tasks/resque.rake

```
require "resque/tasks"
require "resque/scheduler/tasks"

task "resque:preload" => :environment
namespace :resque do
  task :setup do
    require "resque"

  end

  task setup_schedule: :setup do
    require "resque-scheduler"

    Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config","schedule.yml"))
  end

  task scheduler: :setup_schedule
end
```

**UPDATE**

The problem appears to be specifically with Resque-Scheduler. If I remove that from my procfile I can start my app fine with Docker-Compose and I can see perform resque jobs and see them running.

However the scheduler works fine when started with manually or with foreman (not using containers) so I'd like to be able to get it working here also.

Comment: Probably the issue is `Procfile`, because its being called in ones all workers start...

Comment: Is `$REDIS_URL` a full URL, or a host name?  You spell it as URL syntax but then pass it as a host name in the code.

Comment: @7urkm3n what do you mean

Comment: @DavidMaze good catch that was mismatched. I've changed it (and updated the question) but getting `Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a clue from this answer here in the end: [Docker-compose - Redis at 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350679/docker-compose-redis-at-0-0-0-0-instead-of-127-0-0-1)

It seems I needed to set my Resque redis connection in the setup task as well as in the initializer. Adding Resque.redis = Redis.current into my resque.rake setup task finally got it all working:

```
require "resque/tasks"
require "resque/scheduler/tasks"

task "resque:preload" => :environment
namespace :resque do
  task :setup do
    require "resque"

    Resque.redis = Redis.current
  end

  task setup_schedule: :setup do
    require "resque-scheduler"

    Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config","schedule.yml"))
  end

  task scheduler: :setup_schedule
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head a see few things:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        bundle check || bundle install
        bundle exec rake db:migrate; rake db:seed
        bundle exec foreman start
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis --> try better redis://cache
    links:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.5-alpine
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're changing here and why? I tried adding the links section but had the same problem.